# python tkinter image that just being created got the right path but still not showing

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import qrcode; import tkinter as tk; from tkinter import *;from os import path; import os


def Qr_code_maker():
    Or_name = text.get(); Qr_link = Varf.get(); image_qr = qrcode.make(Qr_link); image_qr.save(f"Qrcode {Or_name}.png")
    global image_qr_real
    file_name = f"Qrcode {Or_name}.png"
    #abs_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), file_name)
    image_qr_real = PhotoImage(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), file_name))
    print(image_qr_real)
    b = Label(root,image= image_qr_real)
    b.image = image_qr_real
    b.pack()

root = tk.Tk(); root.title("QR  code maker "); root.geometry("500x750")

fram = tk.Frame(root);fram.pack(side= "top")

text_name = tk.Label(fram,text= "name qr code");text_name.pack(); text = tk.StringVar()

unput_qr_name = tk.Entry(fram, textvariable= text); unput_qr_name.pack()

text_name_1 = tk.Label(fram,text= "link qr code");text_name_1.pack(side= "bottom")

Varf = tk.StringVar(); unput_qr = tk.Entry(root, textvariable= Varf); unput_qr.pack(padx= 20)

buttion = tk.Button(root,text= "entry",command= Qr_code_maker); buttion.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

most of the problem are there and it not showing at all

```
def Qr_code_maker():
    Or_name = text.get(); Qr_link = Varf.get(); image_qr = qrcode.make(Qr_link); image_qr.save(f"Qrcode {Or_name}.png")
    global image_qr_real
    file_name = f"Qrcode {Or_name}.png"
    #abs_file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), file_name)
    image_qr_real = PhotoImage(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), file_name))
    print(image_qr_real)
    b = Label(root,image= image_qr_real)
    b.image = image_qr_real
    b.pack()
```

because i am trying to show a Qr code that i just created with a link and with a universal path but it not working

but it working for local path tho

Comment: What does _"but it not working"_ mean? Do you get an error, and if so, what is the error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)

Comment: You need to use `file` option to pass the image path in `PhotoImage()`, like `PhotoImage(file=...)`.

Comment: @Tranbi OP has already used an attribute of the label to store the reference of the image: `b.image = image_qr_real`. Also `image_qr_real` is a global variable. So it is not a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: @acw1668 you're right! I didn't take enough time to read the code properly. Upvoted your answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `file` option to pass the image path to `PhotoImage()`:

```py
image_qr_real = PhotoImage(file=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), file_name))
```

Comment: ahh thanks now i can send it to my friend :D